# -bash: cd: /tensorflow1: No such file or directory in ubuntu, but the file is there

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and created a virtual environment called *'tensorflow1'* as shown above. I am using putty to access a machine remotely. So I was trying to change directory by typing **"cd /tensorflow1/models/research"** but it says **"-bash: cd: /tensorflow1: No such file or directory"** in ubuntu, but the file is there. I typed **"ls"** and it also shows the file. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

When you type `ls` you see the content of **the current** directory. When you type `cd /tensorflow1` you're trying to enter a directory `tensorflow1` **at the root** (`/`) of the filesystem and the directory is certainly not there. You just need

```
cd tensorflow1/models/research
```

to enter a subdirectory of the current directory. Or

```
cd ./tensorflow1/models/research
```

because `.` means "the current directory".

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `cd ./tensorflow1/models/research`  or just `cd tensorflow1/models/research`.

Read about [root directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_directory), [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory), [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) then about [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)